# Writing code to integrate 1D Fresnel Diffraction in Python

Tags: python, math, physics, numerical-integration

my task is to integrate the following equation for 1d Fresnel diffraction, in red in:

[image: formula]

The point is that you are fourier transforming the aperture to a pattern on the screen, but for now just focussing on integrating the horizontal strip in 1d (ignoring the height for now). yprime is thus ignored. You also have fixed z and k, and j is an imaginary number. I have written the following code for it:

```
import math 
import numpy as np
import cmath 

k=5
z=5
x=0
j=cmath.sqrt(-1)
func=math.exp((j*k/2*z)(x-xp)*(x-xp))
def X(xp1,xp2,function,N):

    h=(xp2-xp1)/N
    y=0.0
    xp=xp1

    for x in np.arange(1, N/2 +1): #summing odd order y terms

        y+=4*f(xp)
        xp+=2*h

    xp=xp1+2*h
    for x in np.arange(0, N/2): #summing even order y terms

        y+=2*f(x)
        xp+=2*h

    integral= (h/3)*(y+f(xp1)+f(xp2))    

    return integral

print(simpson(0,5,func,10))
```

however, it is saying that xp is not defined. but I clearly have defined xp in the function.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: here is a neater version of my code. But it's still asking me to define xp..

```
import math
import cmath

lamda=0.2
k=(2*math.pi)/lamda
z=0.1

def expfunc(x, xp):

    func = math.exp(((1j)*k/2*z)(x-(xp))*(x-(xp)))

    return(func)


def X(xp1,xp2,x,f,N):

    h=(xp2-xp1)/N
    y=0.0
    xp=xp1

    for i in np.arange(1, N/2 +1): #summing odd order y terms

        y+=4*f(xp)
        xp+=2*h

    xp=xp1+2*h
    for i in np.arange(0, N/2): #summing even order y terms

        y+=2*f(xp)
        xp+=2*h

    integral= (h/3)*(y+f(xp1)+f(xp2))    

    return integral

print(X(0,1,x,expfunc,10))
```

Comment: Btw, you don't need `cmath.sqrt(-1)`, `1j` works fine.

Comment: Please roll your question back to it's former state. If you believe your question no longer belongs on the site, then you can delete it. But please do not edit out all of the question details, as it invalidates all of the answers on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use the variable `xp` before you have defined it.

```
import math 
import numpy as np
import cmath 

k=5
z=5
x=0
j=cmath.sqrt(-1)
func=math.exp((j*k/2*z)(x-xp)*(x-xp)) #xp is not defined yet
```

You gave initial values for everything else except `xp`.

Comment: but I put xp=xp1, which the user puts into the function

Answer (score 0):

when you define `func` as you did

```
func=math.exp((j*k/2*z)(x-xp)*(x-xp))
```

you define a single value called `func`. What you probably want is something like that:

```
func = lambda x,xp : math.exp((j*k/2*z)(x-xp)*(x-xp))
```

and then change call of `func` to

```
   y+=4*f(x, xp)
```

and

```
    y+=2*f(x, xp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is `y+=4*f(xp)` inside the first for loop of the function `X`.

At the very end you have `print(X(0,1,x,expfunc,10))` where `expfunc` is acting as `f` in the bit of code `y+=4*f(xp)`. The function `expfunc` takes two arguments, one of them defined as `xp`. Although the variable you pass in `f` is defined with the name `xp`, the function only sees that you have passed in the first argument `x` and not the argument `xp`.

Further, I do not see the variable `x` in `print(X(0,1,x,expfunc,10))` defined anywhere.

Also, the second snipit of code is much different than the first. If the same questions apply then you should remove the first snipit altogether and/or rephrase your questions because from what I see in the second chuck the error you claim to be getting should not be raised.